# jquery ajax load not understanding a certain element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newslinks a').click(function() {
     var url=$(this).attr('href');
     $('#headlines').load(url + ' #newsItem');
     return false;
  }); //end click
}); // end ready



<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <p class="logo">JavaScript <i>&</i> jQuery <i class="mm">The<br>Missing<br>Manual</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>News Headlines</h1>
      <ul id="newslinks">
        <li><a href="today.html">Today&#8217;s News</a></li>
        <li><a href="yesterday.html">Yesterday&#8217;s News</a></li>
        <li><a href="lastweek.html">Last Week&#8217;s News</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="headlines"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The part that I don't get is in here:

```
$('#headlines').load(url + ' #newsItem');
```

What exactly does `#newsItem` do here?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector inside `load` after the URL will load that specific element's content into your target element. `$('#headlines').load(url + ' #newsItem');` loads the URL, then within, finds `#newsItem`, and loads that content into `#headlines`